# Deciding on whether to use Bool Check or Try/Catch when checking if String exists in Array

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script

I have no code to share for this particular question as its more of a question of what is a better design choice performance wise.

When checking to see if a string exist in a sheet, would it be best to iterate through a column, get the values. if the value we are searching for is found make a bool true? or would it be best to encapsulate the iteration in a try block and if the string is not found; catch it as a NullReferenceException?

```
 range = s1.getRange("A2:A").getValues()
 
 for(var i=0;i<range.length;i++) {
 if(range[i][0] === "searchableString") {
 stringFound = true;
```

or would it be best to do

```
 try {
 for(var i=0;i<range.length;i++) {
 if(range[i][0] === "searchableString") {
 catch(err) {
 err = console.log("string not found, move on");
      }
   }
 }
```

any advice would be greatly appreciated. Thanks

Using a boolean works but I'm wondering if a try and catch logic block would be beneficial on the offchance the string we are searching for is not found; it can catch the null reference error and move to the next block of code (Whatever that may be)

Comment: Where would the thrown exception come from? The code doesn't really make much sense.

Comment: Am I wrong to assume if the string does not exist in a column you are iterating through it wouldn't throw a null reference exception?

Comment: It might in some cases, but your `try catch` syntax is wrong anyway. The `try` and the `catch` must be at the same lexical nesting level.

Comment: Generally relying on exception handling for ordinary logic is bad, because exception handling is very hard for the JavaScript runtime to optimize.

Answer (score 0):

The best practice is to use [Array](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array) methods, like this:

```
  const displayValues = s1.getRange('A2:A').getValues().flat();
  const stringFound = displayValues.includes('searchableString');
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered using the ["TextFinder"](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/text-finder) Class? If what you are searching for is not found, it will only return an empty value instead of an error.

You can search on an entire Google Spreadsheet, a specific sheet, or a range. Also, you can use the method "findAll()," which will return all cells matching the search criteria in an [Array](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_arrays.asp) or you can use the method "getCurrentMatch()" to get the current cell matching the search criteria.

Here are some samples using "findAll()"

---

**Search the entire Google spreadsheet:**

```
function searchEntireSheet() {
  // get the active spreadsheet and creates the finder
  let textFinder = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().createTextFinder("mobile").findAll();

  // this is just to view the sheet and cell where the data is located 
  // this is just for testing and is not necessary
  for (let i = 0; i < textFinder.length; i++) {
    sheet = textFinder[i].getSheet().getName()
    cell = textFinder[i].getA1Notation()
    console.log("sheet: " + sheet + "\n" + "cells: "+ cell)
   }
}
```

**Result:**

[image]

---

**Search an Specific Sheet:**

```
function searchSpecificSheet() {
// get the active sheet and creates the finder
  let textFinder = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName("Test 1")
                    .createTextFinder("mobile").findAll();
  // this is just to view the cell where the data is located 
  // this is just for testing and is not necessary
  for (let i = 0; i < textFinder.length; i++) {
    cell = textFinder[i].getA1Notation()
    console.log("cells: "+ cell)
   }
}
```

**Result:**

[image]

---

**Search under an specific range:**

```
function searchSpecificCell() {
  // get the Range and creates the finder
  let textFinder = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName("Test 1")
  .getRange("B:B").createTextFinder("mobile").findAll();
  
  // this is just to view the cell where the data is located 
  // this is just for testing and is not necessary
  for (let i = 0; i < textFinder.length; i++) {
    cell = textFinder[i].getA1Notation()
    console.log("cells: "+ cell)
   }
}
```

**Result:**

[image]

---

You can replace  `.findAll()` with `.getCurrentMatch()` in any of those samples, and it will return just one cell.

Lastly, if it doesn't find the value, it will return an empty value without errors. Like this:

[image]